# Gatling won't save access token

Tags: javascript, performance, gatling, scala-gatling

In this example below, I can see that path to token is correct, because when I change it I get errors such as find.exists. found nothing. Yet for some reason I can't save the token. I get Failed to build request: No attribute named 'Token' is defined

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.jsonpath.JsonPath

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._
import io.gatling.jsonpath.AST._

class Uus extends Simulation {

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseUrl("https://testsite.com")
        .inferHtmlResources()
        .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36")

    val autentimata = Map(
        "Access-Control-Request-Headers" -> "authorization",
        "Access-Control-Request-Method" -> "GET",
        "Origin" -> "https://testsite.com")

    val autentitud = Map(
        "Accept" -> "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Origin" -> "https://testsite.com",
        "authorization" -> "Bearer ${Token}")

    val uri2 = "https://testsite.com"

    val scn = scenario("RecordedSimulation")

        .exec(http("savingtoken")
            .options("/token/get?rememberMe=true")
            .headers(autentimata)
            .resources(http("request_2")
            .get("/token/get?rememberMe=true")
           // .check(jsonPath("$.data.accessToken").saveAs("Token"))
            .check(status.is(200), jsonPath("$.data.accessToken").ofType[String].saveAs("Token"))
            .headers(autentimata)
            .basicAuth("11111111111","P2rooliall"),
            http("sisselogitud")
            .options("/users/11111111111")
            .headers(autentimata),
            http("kasutaja lehele")
            .get("/users/11111111111")
            .headers(autentitud)
            //.check(jsonPath("$.data.accessToken").saveAs("token"))
            .check(status.is(200)),
            http("sündmuste lehele")
            .options("/events?page=0&size=25&relation=ASSIGNEE,CREATOR&status=OPEN,REOPEN,FINISHED,ARCHIVED&sort=createdDate,desc")
            .headers(autentimata),
            http("sündmusteleht")
            .get("/events?page=0&size=25&relation=ASSIGNEE,CREATOR&status=OPEN,REOPEN,FINISHED,ARCHIVED&sort=createdDate,desc")
            .headers(autentitud)
            .header("authorization", "Bearer ${Token}")


    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

Comment: do you intend to have all your requests (except for "savingtoken") be part of resources? All of these will be fetched in parallel and so ${Token} probably won't be set when you come to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is in this line :

> "authorization" -> "Bearer ${Token}"

from this block:

```scala
 val autentitud = Map(
        "Accept" -> "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Origin" -> "https://testsite.com",
        "authorization" -> "Bearer ${Token}")
```

since `No attribute named 'Token' is defined` states that you are trying to use a variable not yet defined. And ,indeed, you save `Token` only during scenario execution.

Gatling documentation states  [Expession EL](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/) :

> This Expression Language only works on String values being passed to Gatling DSL methods. **Such Strings are parsed only once, when the Gatling simulation is being instanciated.**

So the solution would be to refactor your code and pass the block inside headers, even if it would mean a code duplication.

And you could try to verify that your token is extracted by printing its value out like this:

```scala
.exec{
        session=>{
                println(" Token value" + session("Token").as[String])
                session

      }}
```